# How to find length of largest contiguous segment which forms an arithmetic progression in range [L R] of a given array of length N?

Tags: algorithm, math

Consider Array `1 2 3 5 5`

1. for query `[L R D]=[1 5 1]`, output is 3
2. for query `[1 1 1]`, output is 1

Also there are Q queries to this questions where `0<Q<10^6` so Brute Forces is not working !

*Note: indexing starts at 1*

*Note2: D represents common difference of AP*

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow ! Could you add more examples as to what you want to achieve ? It's kind of difficult with that phrasing and only one test case.

Comment: Like an Array [1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 3 1 1 1 1 5 6]
If a query is given to find maximum length of subarray consisting of 1 in range[L,R]
for eg between [4 8]
taking indexing from 1
ans will come out to be 3

Comment: @KnightKnight Give example output for a given example input, edit your question to add such examples.

Comment: L means index we start at R index we end at !! and D represents value of which we have to find length of max subarray !

Comment: Does your index start with 0 or 1?

Comment: it starts at 1 ! SIR

Comment: I'm sorry, this is completely unclear what you're asking. Please edit your question to have at least 4 clearly structured test cases. Each test has an **input**, a **query** and an **output**. Please use carriage returns to structure your test cases.

Comment: The `D represents...` explanation requires further elaboration, I think.

Comment: I will edit it once for all !

Comment: are L and R both inclusive? range[1, 4] of [1 1 1 2 0] = [1 1 1 2] ?

Comment: they are both inclusive

Comment: Still completely unclear to me after your edits. I'm voting to close.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find the longest arithmetic progression inside a sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43151904/find-the-longest-arithmetic-progression-inside-a-sequence)

Answer (score 0):

Your question can be simplified to find the length longest arithmetic progression with the given common difference, with the array = `[L, R]` and size`n = R - L + 1`

You can then find to solution from [Geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/longest-arithmetic-progression-with-the-given-common-difference/)

> **Naive Approach**: For each element calculate the length of the longest AP it could form and print the maximum among them. It involves
>   O(n^2) time complexity.
>
> An efficient approach is to use **Hashing**.
>
> Create a map where the key is the starting element of an AP and its
>   value is the number of elements in that AP. The idea is to update the
>   value at key ‘a'(which is at index i and whose starting element is not
>   yet there in the map) by 1 whenever the element at index j(>i) could
>   be in the AP of ‘a'(as the starting element). Then we print the
>   maximum value among all values in the map.